# Angular SPA with base-href can not find resources

Tags: .net, angular, single-page-application

We need a dotnet mvc running on root url (example.com) and an angular spa running on sub url (example.com/spa).
To reach this goal i have set the base-href in index.html to "/spa/" and the "program.cs" looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "spa")),
    RequestPath = "/spa"
});
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/spa"))
    {
        await next();
        return;
    }

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "spa/dist";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer("start");
    }
});

app.Run();
```

The call of "example.com" serves the expected "Hello World!", "example.com/spa" is a blank page and all resources like "example.com/spa/styles.css" return status 404.
In console there is also an error message:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      √ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

How can i fix this problem?

I am using the latest versions of dotnet and angular.

**Edit:**

This is the content of the csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>DotNetMVC_Angular</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What exactly do i need in this File?

**Edit 2:**

Created a brand new Project with "dotnet new angular" and changed the base href to "/spa/". Same behavior, all resources got 404.

Comment: please add the content of your csproj file, you should have sg like <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot> and <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />

Comment: i would recomment just looking at the starter project for the configuration its an vs template